# open a javascript (.JS) file from c#

Tags: javascript, c#

How to open a .js file from c# winform? I tried this

```
Process.Start(@"C:\...\software.exe", @"C:\...\mergescripts.js");
```

but it's not working. Manually, I can load the mergescripts.js file into my on software.exe using open file. But how to do it dynamically using button event from c#?

Comment: Does your "software.exe" take a javascript file as an argument?

Comment: yes it takes java script file as argument

Comment: Just use `StreamReader();` , read all your js code and save it to a string... You can find information about Streamreader on MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Great.. so what does "not working" entail? errors? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: i am not receiving any errors. i am able to open software.exe, but the file mergescript.js is not loading.

Comment: You need to debug your own program, we don't know what "software.exe" is so its going to be impossible to say why your program isn't working.

Comment: What do you try to achieve in your application ? Ok, let's assume that user opens js file from some location but what then ? Do you want to execute this js code in browser or just open it ?

Comment: i just need to open it

Answer (score 0):

[JintEngine](https://github.com/cosh/Jint) can be used to execute JavaScript:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.js", FileMode.Open))
{
    JintEngine js = JintEngine.Load(fs);
    object result = js.Run("return status;");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: what is the  c# reference i need to add for using jint?

Comment: Click on the link in my answer. It's a link to GitHub where you can download JintEngine. Then you need to add it to your C# project.

Comment: i added the Jint.dll into my c#. But am getting error as name "JintEngine" does not exist in the current context. i have added "using Jint.Runtime.Interop;"

Comment: i tried that also. not working..anything else i am missing?

Comment: 1.) Include the DLL's into your project (either download them or get the nuget package, if available)
2.) Add a reference to your project ("Add Reference" menu button)
3.) add the `using` to your file where you use the JintEngine classes.

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.js", FileMode.Open))
            {
                JintEngine js = JintEngine.Load(fs);
                object result = js.Run("return status;");
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        }. This is how am using ur code. but getting error at JintEngine. Followed the 3 steps you mentioned

Comment: I gave you an acceptable answer on how to deal with your problem. Integrating a DLL into a project is beginner's stuff. Please try to handle this yourself, I can't look at your computer and see what you're doing, but adding a DLL is really simple, much simpler than anything else regarding your issue.

Answer (score -1):

please try with below syntax

```
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
        ps.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe";
        ps.Arguments = @"C:\Users\Desktop\aaa.txt";
        Process.Start(ps);
```

Comment: Wrong. The command line parameter goes in the second argument of `Process.Start`. Also, you have to put stuff with spaces in quotes or it will be interpreted as two commandline arguments.

Comment: After your edit, your code works and opens a textfile with notepad++. But the OP's question is how to execute JavaScript. So, your answer is still unrelated.